# Windows 10 Credentials Manager: 'Generic Credential' that I don't recognize - Identify and trace source?

Tags: windows-10, credentials-manager

Found a Windows 10 **'Generic Credential'** under **Credentials Manager** in Control Panel.

I didn't create this credential and I don't recognize the username or password.

Could anyone inform me as to how to trace the program or connection that created this credential?

Is this indicative of malware/virus or some kind of network hacking attempt?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You are going to have to provide us a little more detail.  I took a look at a default stock Windows 10 1703 VM I have and it does not have a "generic credential" that is stored.

Comment: Each program under Generic Credential has a name. I too have a suspicious looking entry called: VirtualApp/didlogical with a username that starts with 02 followed by some letters. Apparently its part of Microsoft Life.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently remove that credential and prevent it coming back? Could you shed more light on where it came from, what program created it and why?